# String Request Unexpected response Code 415

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

When I'm using Postman,
Putting values from raw works perfectly.
But in Android, I am receiving Error Code 415.

```
 REVIEW_URL = "http://somesite.esy.es/api.php/registration";
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REVIEW_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("RESPONSE:", response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("ERROR",""+error.getMessage());
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put("device_id", "11111");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/raw";
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/raw");
            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(request);
```

[image]

Am I doing it right chaging content type to raw? thanks.

Comment: Pls post your Postman screenshot

Comment: i have added my postman screenshot. thanks

Comment: Please use `"application/json; charset=utf-8";` instead of `"application/raw";` inside both `getBodyContentType` and `getHeaders`

Comment: it gaves me this error..  Call to undefined function App\Tygh\Api\Formats\__() in <b>/home/u500284875/public_html/App/Tygh/Api/Formats/Json.php</b> on line <b>51</b><br />

Comment: IMO, you should check/debug your web service

Comment: yes, '/Api/Formats/Json.php'

Comment: what is your content type?

Answer (score 0):

your content type is not supported, so I suggest changing it to

> *"application/json"*

this worked for me.

[image]

as shown here, this is the correct one.

[image]

thanks, hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

JsonObjectRequest  use this Volly Object is right.

Comment: when you post some data with the json format,That the right way is JsonObjectRequest.so this way is not 415 code.like this .   [link](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/)